# How can I append objects inside an array using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to push req.body inside an array and adding them into the firestore and when i am doing this i am not able to append the response one after the other in the array instead it gets overwritten with the latest req.body and here are my tried method.

```
app.post("/webhook", async (req, res) => {
try{
    const phoneNumber = req.body.data.source;
    console.log(req.body.data.source);
    const profileSnapshot = await db
      .collection("Profiles")
      .where("phoneNumber", "==", `${phoneNumber}`)
      .get();
      if (profileSnapshot.docs.length === 1) {console.log('known)}
      else{
           console.log("unknown");
      const converstations = [];
      const outbound = [];
      if (
        req.body.data.content.text === "Hi" ||
        req.body.data.content.text === "hi"
      ) {
        converstations.push(JSON.stringify(req.body));

      

      }
      if (req.body.data.content.text === "1") {
        converstations.push(JSON.stringify(req.body));

        console.log("sending a link to the website for signup");
      } else if (req.body.data.content.text === "2") {
        converstations.push(JSON.stringify(req.body));

        console.log(
          "Add contact /upload"
        );
      }
      await db
        .collection("WhatsappConversations")
        .doc(getISO8601Date())
        .collection("Conversations")
        .doc(phoneNumber)
        .set(
          {
            conversation: converstations,
            timestamp: Date.now(),
          },
          { merge: true }
        );
      }
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})
```

and i want data to store in this format

```
{
conversations:[{},{},{}],
timestamp:Date.now()}
```

Comment: Because you initialize `const converstations = []` every time the API is called.

Comment: @holydragon so how can i append then ?

Comment: That's because each time the API is called `conversations` is initialized again.

Comment: @luciferluci One ugly option that may be a workaround for you now is to declare `let converstations = []` globally.

Comment: You can store conversation in a separate collection and read the conversation from the collection and create an array from conversations array from that collection and then update the conversations.

Comment: @holydragon using let i am getting the same response

Comment: @luciferluci declare it globally.

Comment: @holydragon i think when i am declaring globally and try to when i receive from other phoneNumber it will create a mess

Comment: @luciferluci So, in that case you do as Balaj Khan suggests.

Comment: @holydragon i think his approach will slow down the process